# phpwkhtmltopdf にて生成した PDF にパスワードを設定できるか

Tags: php, pdf

いつもお世話になっております。

phpwkhtmltopdf を利用して PDF を生成しておりますが、こちらにパスワードを設定することは可能でしょうか。
ドキュメントを読み、そのような記述がなかったため、疑問に思った次第です。
https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf

phpwkhtmltopdf のバージョンは 2.2 を利用しております。

恐れ入りますが、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

`phpwkhtmltopdf`は`wkhtmltopdf`のラッパーですが、その`wkhtmltopdf`にパスワードで保護する機能が無いため、「設定できない」です。

https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2808